# Define a new macro for tabu environment

Tags: tables, macros, tabu

I recently found [this github repo](https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/blob/master/examples/yFlatTable/yFlatTableShowcase.pdf) which has a package called yFlatTable.
[image] It is beautiful and I want to use it for my German note (making vocab list and their usage, or lecture note, etc). But when I run the example file, it shows no color, which I believe might be due to the tabu package's coloring. I tried to fix it but it didn't work out.
[image]

I want to create a table of this styling and for reproducing purposes I want to define a macro to call it when needed. I'm not competent in LaTeX and having a hard time finding a good documentation on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated, you can use any package you want.

Comment: The `tabu` package is currently unmaintained (https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/)  and has quite a few bugs, especially regarding color.

Comment: An alternative could be the `tabularx` package (or `xltabular` if you need page breaks inside of a table)  in combination with `colortbl` (`\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`)  for the background color.

Comment: In one of their last changes the placed the comment "Remove tabu from yReport " so when there is still a reference you should contact the maintainer of the package or is the issue https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX/issues/15 already by you?

Comment: @albert  Yup that's me. I don't think that the repo owner would reply in any soon (last commit was 2 years ago) so I decided to bring the question here.

Comment: Well the last commit I do see is from February 1, 2020 (5 Months ago), just is little bit less than 2 years ago (but yes time flies).